rust Arc<dyn Any + Sync + Send> does not work in some situation
I have code like :
fn main() {
    // works
    let this_is_arc_string = Arc::new("this is &str".to_string());
    foo(&Some(this_is_arc_string.clone()));
    // wrap with option
    let this_is_arc_string_wrapped_by_option = Some(this_is_arc_string.clone());
    // this will return true
    println!("is same : {}",&Some(this_is_arc_string.clone()).eq(&this_is_arc_string_wrapped_by_option));
    // compiler : "mismatched types[E0308]"
    foo(&this_is_arc_string_wrapped_by_option);
}

fn foo(args: &Option<Arc<dyn Any + Sync + Send>>) {}

why the first shit works and the second shit doesnt work ?
here is the error message :

mismatched types [E0308]
expected &Option<Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync>>, found &Option<Arc<String>>
Note: expected reference &std::option::Option<Arc<(dyn Any + Send + Sync + 'static)>> found reference &std::option::Option<Arc<std::string::String>>
Help: std::string::String implements Any so you could box the found value and coerce it to the trait object Box<dyn Any>, you will have to change the expected type as well
Note: function defined here

I wannna know why

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Please put the full error from cargo check, not your IDE.

"I wannna know why" - Arc<String> and Arc<dyn Any> are different types (and even different sizes) but the former can be coerced into the latter. Unfortunately though this_is_arc_string_wrapped_by_option is a Option<Arc<String>> which cannot be coerced into a Option<Arc<dyn Any>>. It happens to work in the first call because type-inference sees through the & and Some that this_is_arc_string.clone() needs to be a Arc<dyn Any> and does the coercion there before the Option is built.
